# Scala parser combinators, parsers fails due to precedence

Tags: parsing, scala, parser-combinators, operator-precedence

I am trying to write an interpreter for the programming language Icon. One of the steps in this process is writing a parser for Icon, which I've done in the following way:

```
import java.io.FileReader
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical._
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.JavaTokenParsers

abstract class expr
case class CstInt(val value : Int) extends expr
case class FromTo(val from : expr, val to : expr) extends expr
case class Write(val value : expr) extends expr
case class And(val e1 : expr, val e2 : expr) extends expr
case class Or(val e1 : expr, val e2 : expr) extends expr

object ExprParser extends JavaTokenParsers with PackratParsers{

lazy val exp : PackratParser[expr] = andexp | exp2

lazy val exp2 : PackratParser[expr] = fromTo | exp3

lazy val exp3 :PackratParser[expr] = orexp | exp4 

lazy val exp4 : PackratParser[expr] = integer | exp5

lazy val exp5 : PackratParser[expr] = write 

lazy val integer : PackratParser[expr] = wholeNumber ^^ { s => CstInt(s.toInt)}

lazy val  write : PackratParser[Write] =  "write" ~> "(" ~> exp <~ ")" ^^ {  e => Write(e)}

lazy val fromTo : PackratParser[FromTo] = ("(" ~> integer) ~ ("to" ~> integer <~ ")") ^^ { case from ~ to => FromTo(from, to)}

lazy val andexp : PackratParser[And] = exp ~ ("&" ~> exp) ^^ { case e1 ~ e2 => And(e1, e2)}

lazy val orexp : PackratParser[Or] = exp ~ ("|" ~> exp) ^^ { case e1 ~ e2 => Or(e1, e2)}

def parseInput(input: String) : expr =
    parseAll (exp, input) match {
        case Success(tree, _) => tree
        case e: NoSuccess => throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.toString())
    }

}

object Interpret {
def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {
    println(ExprParser.parseInput(args(0)))
    }
}
```

However, I've run into a few problems when I try to parse the following expression:

```
write((1 to 4) | 4)
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [9.17] failure: `)' expected but ` ' found
```

Whereas parsing

```
write((1 to 4) & 4)
```

works just fine. The first expression works fine if I move the orexp parser to an exp group above the fromto parser. However, this does not adhere to the rules given by Icon, and does not solve the underlying problem.

Does anyone have any ideas for solutions? According to the Scala docs, mixing packrat parsers and regular parsers should be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have read the [paper](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/attachment/1956909/0/packrat_parsers.pdf) on packrat parsers in Scala, and I'm afraid this grammar won't work as is. The problem being that `fromTo` as `exp` inside `write`, and then `write` itself fails (and, having no other alternatives, the outer `exp` fails). It never goes back and say *"well, let's see if there's another `exp` that is also valid"*.

However, looking at [this text](http://www.tools-of-computing.com/tc/CS/iconprog.pdf), I don't see `fromTo` having parenthesis as part of its grammar. If it were simply rewritten to remove those parenthesis from that level, it would work:

```
object ExprParser extends JavaTokenParsers with PackratParsers{
  lazy val exp : PackratParser[expr] = andexp | exp2
  lazy val exp2 : PackratParser[expr] = fromTo | exp3
  lazy val exp3 :PackratParser[expr] = orexp | exp4 
  lazy val exp4 : PackratParser[expr] = integer | exp5
  lazy val exp5 : PackratParser[expr] = write | exp6
  lazy val exp6 : PackratParser[expr] = "(" ~> exp <~ ")"
  lazy val integer : PackratParser[expr] = wholeNumber ^^ { s => CstInt(s.toInt)}
  lazy val  write : PackratParser[Write] =  "write" ~> "(" ~> exp <~ ")" ^^ {  e => Write(e)}
  lazy val fromTo : PackratParser[FromTo] = integer ~ ("to" ~> integer) ^^ { case from ~ to => FromTo(from, to)}
  lazy val andexp : PackratParser[And] = exp ~ ("&" ~> exp) ^^ { case e1 ~ e2 => And(e1, e2)}
  lazy val orexp : PackratParser[Or] = exp3 ~ ("|" ~> exp) ^^ { case e1 ~ e2 => Or(e1, e2)}
}
```

Comment: I was not aware that normal Scala parsers do not backtrack, do you know why that is so? I now tried changing first just fromto to a packratparser, and after that everything. However, none of this changed the problem.

Comment: @ChrKroer It didn't? I have made a smaller test case (mainly because the example you posted refers to external types), and it worked fine. The again, there were small differences between what I tried and what is actually happening (specifically, `fromto` being fully accepted, and then the closing `)` of `write` not being found). Out of curiosity, if you condense all the `expN` definitions into a single giant `exp` definition with many `|`, does it work?

Comment: Nope, that did not work either. I'll just try and update the code in the original post to reflect how it looks now with packpratparsers all over the place.

Comment: @ChrKroer Mind you, my problem is with the types `FromTo`, `Or`, `Prim`, etc. In other words, I can compile that by itself. You could paste a gist for the complete code, if possible, though it would be a better exercise for you to try to build the minimal example possible that shows the problem.

Comment: right, I've changed the code to an example that has the same problem, and can run completely on its own, with the parsed strings given on the command line. Thanks for help so far btw!

Comment: I know the history has been edited, but normal parsers absolutely do backtrack. It's just that non-packrat parsers will loop to death on left recursion, which is how your grammar is written so you either use packrats or get rid of the left recursion.

Comment: One slight optimization, andexp = exp2 ~ ("&" ~> exp).  Why?  Because the exp to the left can't be an andexp.

Comment: @Daniel thanks, it works! 


@James this code is simplified though. For the real parser, I need to have have several expression types in a category before the andexp, which can all be used in andexpressions. For that reason, I don't really see a way of getting rid of the recursion.

Comment: @ChrKroer He's right. In fact, that's how the grammar on the paper I linked is written. A chain "a & b &" should be parsed as "exp2 & andexp", so you can write precisely that. Or take orexp, for instance, which can be written as `exp4 ~ ("|" ~> exp)`. In the case of `a & b | c`, it will decompose first as `andexp` -- `exp2 ~ ("&" ~> exp)` -- and, then, the second `exp` expands as an `orexp`.

Comment: @James I think "backtrack" can be argued. The `|` operator will take the left hand if it parses, or the right hand if it doesn't -- that doesn't make it backtracking. But consider the problem posed:  `exp` got accepted, and then the parser that included it failed, instead of backtracking into `exp` and trying to make it succeed in some other way. I do wish these mechanisms were enunciated in the scaladocs, in a manner clear and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no guru at this, but to fix your problem, I first grouped your expressions into a single line, like this:

```
lazy val exp : PackratParser[expr] = (andexp | orexp | fromTo | integer | write)
```

And then I changed the order you had - fromTo was listed before orexp.

Seems to work fine now.

Andrés

Comment: Changing the order changes the semantic, so that is not possible -- he said so in the question.